# Get current request in nodejs independently(?)

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I get the current request object in nodejs?
Or at least its current `Content-Type` or `methods`.

I see **PHP** has something like this

```php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Is there any `available` in **NodeJs**? similar to **PHP**?

I tried getting the documentation of node `http` module I got nothing of the same.

I am using **ExpressJS**, but I want to create a **simple function**, that gets the current request without passing the request object from **express.Request** like the sample code below:

```
const requestValid = () => ["PUT", "PATCH"].includes(// current request)
```

Comment: `request.method`. Just `console.log(request)` :)

Comment: I guess, that's not what I wanted, I've updated my question @AikonMogwai

Comment: There is no global "current request" variable. You're supposed to pass `req` around to the functions that need to inspect it.

Comment: A `node.js` is a not `php`. See express-`middleware` to validation and another things.

Comment: @AikonMogwai, is it due to nodejs's concurrency?. when I put a global req, then there's a chance that a new instance would read the old request value from the old instance? just a guess though

Comment: Each `request`-instance is independent. A typical Express-solution to request validation is middleware as function with signature `function validation (req, res, next)` and using is `app.get('/some-path', validation, (req, res, next) => {...router code...})`.

Comment: @Reyn Yes. Although node.js is single-threaded it is concurrent. Any global variable is accessible to all current requests. Although each incoming request cannot be processed in parallel (single threaded) and each response does not happen in parallel I/O in between (database request, reading templates from disk etc.) means multiple requests can be in process simultaneously before the first to complete (not necessarily the first incoming request) writes a response

Comment: @Reyn What exactly are you trying to do? It looks like you are trying to implement some sort of permission system

Comment: @slebetman im just trying to create a function that just verifies the current request. filter purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for, but this is **not** a good idea:

```
let currentRequest = null;

app.use(function(req, res, err, next) {
    currentRequest = req;       
    next();
});
```

This way you can get the current request in the global scope. 
**Do not do this!**. Nodejs or ExpressJs are not designed to handle requests in the global scope.

> Once your app is serving concurrent requests, this will be a source of endless bugs. - AKX

ExpressJS is not like PHP. You have to use request handler callbacks like @Pasha did in his answer.

Comment: Once your app is serving concurrent requests, this will be a source of endless bugs.

Comment: Not hate, but "should not be done" implies it can nevertheless be done – and it really can't be done safely.

Comment: Then I'd reword the answer to quite strongly say that this will not be safe at any scale... People tend to blindly copy-paste the simplest code that at first glance might do the trick, unfortunately :)

Comment: @AKX I made some changes, hope this is more direct.

Comment: @Reijo A more appropriate wording is **"You must not do this!"**. Or **"Don't do this!"**

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have next code in your index.js

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
   console.log(request);
   response.end('Hello World!');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)
server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
       return console.log('Error occured', err)
    }
    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
});
```

So `request` will contain `request.headers` and other fields

Version with Express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const requestValid = () => ["PUT", "PATCH"].includes(/* your code here */)
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('App is listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering what your code looks like and considering your comments it looks like what you are trying to do is perform some logic on each request and verify that a request is allowed. That is in fact the entire design philosophy behind Express.js: to allow functions to perform some logic on requests.

Express is a middleware/plugin engine. In fact, very unlike other frameworks in other languages Express is **only** a middleware/plugin engine. Even route endpoints are actually in theory middlewares that just happen to not be in the middle.

A middleware in Express is just an ordinary function. Express will pass to its middleware three arguments: the `request` object, the `response` object and a `next` function/callback. This is true even for your endpoints - it's just that you're deliberately not using `next()`:

```
function middlewareExample (req, res, next) {
    next(); // continue processing
}

function routeExample (req, res) { // not declaring next is 
                                   // not a syntax error in js
    res.send('hello');
}
```

An Express app is just a big stack of middlewares - it's basically an array of filters (with routing logic) that processes an http request. How Express works is that if you don't call `next()` it will stop processing the request. Therefore to validate connections you just need to do something like:

```
function myValidationMiddleware (req, res, next) {
    // "req" is the current connection.
    // For more info on req see https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req

    if (req.headers['content-type'] == something &&
        ['PUT','PATCH'].includes(req.method)
    ) {
        next(); // allow express to continue processing
    }
    else {
        res.status(403);
        res.send(`You're not allowed to do that`);
    }
}
```

That's it. Just a function. No fancy classes to extend and no special syntax. There are various ways to use middlewares:

You can install it on the entire app:

```
app.use(myValidationMiddleware);
```

You can install it on a specific route:

```
const apiRouter = require('./lib/myApi');
app.use('/api', myValidationMiddleware, apiRouter);
```

You can install it on individual endpoints:

```
app.put('/api/do/something', myValidationMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello');
});
```

etc.

Express is very flexible especially if you also utilize the power of node modules which allows you to import your validation function/middleware anywhere you need it in your code.